# I'm having difficulties with flask_bootstrap4

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use flask_bootstrap4 for my flask project and I copied the snippet code from flask_bootstrap documentation and gives me errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
            {% block styles %}
                <!-- Bootstrap CSS and Custom css -->
                {{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=style.css) }}">
            {% endblock styles %}

            {% if title %}
                <title>Community Helper - {{ title }}</title>
            {% else %}
                <title>Comminity Helper</title>
            {% endif %}

        {% endblock head %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% from 'bootstrap/nav.html' import render_nav_item %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light border">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {{ render_nav_item('index', 'Home') }}
                {{ render_nav_item('about', 'About') }}
            </div>
        </nav>

        {% block script %}
            <!-- Javascript -->
            {{ bootstrap.load_js() }}
        {% endblock script %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
[2019-07-18 15:06:13,553] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/application.py", line 10, in index
    return render_template("index.html")
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/templates/layout.html", line 4, in top-level template code
    {% block head %}
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/templates/index.html", line 4, in block "head"
    {{ super() }}
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/templates/layout.html", line 8, in block "head"
    {% block styles %}
  File "/home/energy/Documents/flask-app/comhelper/templates/layout.html", line 10, in block "styles"
    {{ bootstrap.load_css() }}
  File "/home/energy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'bootstrap' is undefined
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2019 15:06:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but here I'm trying to use the flask extension(flask_bootstrap)

Comment: have you tried to uninstall then reinstall the package again ? pip uninstall flask_bootstrap -> pip install flask_bootstrap

Comment: fortunately I've tried it, the problem remains unresolved

Comment: From your config file have you add 'from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap' ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you imported and initialised flask-bootstrap with:

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
```

and then:

```
Bootstrap(app)
# or bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

in your __init__.py (or wherever else you initialise libraries)?

Answer (score 0):

From the [migration page of Bootstrap-Flask](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate/) if you were using flask-bootstrap before, make sure you remove it before using bootstrap-flask.

```
$ pip uninstall flask-bootstrap bootstrap-flask
$ pip install bootstrap-flask
```